# How can I prettify Join Result on Rest API response object?

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest, api

I started learning about building REST API using PHP as core language and I came into issue with creating response object. I have table users and user_social inside my MySQL database. What I am trying to achieve is to get response object to be like this:

```
{
    id,
    name,
    age,
    social: [
        twitter,
        facebook,
        github
    ]
}
```

My sql query looks like this currently:

```
select users.id, users.name, users.age, user_social.* from users inner join user_social on users.id = user_social.user_id limit 10;
```

And my JSON response looks like this currently:

```
{
    id,
    name,
    age,
    twitter,
    facebook,
    github
}
```

So the question is, how can I group results from join to be in structure like I want to be? Is there MySQL way or I should map it by looping through each record inside PHP and then send response.

Comment: How does the user_social table look like?

Comment: `id,
user_id,
twitter,
facebook,
github`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL just returns rows and fields. You should reformat it with PHP.